# dynamic string array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I created a fixed lenght string:

```
string fileRows[900];
```

But sometimes I need more than 900, and sometimes it would be enough 500.

and after that I need to fill the array with a file rows:

```
...
    string sIn;
    int i = 1;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(szFileName);
    infile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    while ( getline(infile,sIn ) ) // 0. elembe kiterjesztés
    {
        fileRows[i] = sIn;
        i++;
    }
```

How can i create dynamic lenght for this array?

Comment: Use a [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), vector is known as dynamic array:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> fileRows(900);
```

Actually you could just reserve the space for elements and call `push_back`:

```
std::vector<std::string> fileRows;
fileRows.reserve(900);   

while (std::getline(infile, sIn))
{
   fileRows.push_back(sIn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine, but if i would like to read the 2. rows how can I do it?  fileRows[2] doesnt work.

Comment: not before you push_back at least 2 elements. you could always check vector size before call operator[].

Comment: Ohh I found it: fileRows.at(1)